# Python: why is `return` not allowed in a module

Tags: python, module, return

If you look at the Python bytecode compiled from modules, you'll see at the end:

```
10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
13 RETURN_VALUE
```

I.e. a `return` is perfectly valid at the root level of a module. However, if you try to use it in the source code, you get:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Why?

---

This is of course a language design decision. But why was it taken? A `return` is often quite useful in a module. E.g. I sometimes want to write this code at the beginning of a module:

```
import sys
if sys.platform != "linux2":
    print "your platform is not yet supported"
    # define some stubs
    def foo(): pass
    def bar(): pass
    return
```

And I don't want to raise an exception there (because that would result in the module not loading which I don't want).

---

Actually, I hacked some code together which can manipulate the Python bytecode on the fly and just do the return (or in my case jump to the end where the return is done). This works. The only reason it is CPython only is because there is no standard way to manipulate a code object.

[Here](https://github.com/albertz/playground/blob/master/test_importearlyexit.py) is the code.

---

For possible answers: I would prefer real evidence, some past statements from Guido van Rossum or so about this, not so much just any random discussion. I of course can this of both advantages (as presented already) and disadvantages myself but I don't really see the big reason against it.

Comment: why wouldnt you just raise an exception? that will stop execution and return info about why it is up to the caller to listen for the exception

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It will not load the module. I am speaking of cases where I still want to load the module.

Comment: then have a separate module that the user can import ... if its not supported it should not be supported...  in the `__init__.py` you can do `try:import no_linux2; except:import alt_implementation as no_linux2`

Comment: to do what your trying to do is not very good design,,, I would seriously rethink it

Comment: If part of the module is useable and the other part isn't, then arguably, they should be split into submodules which handle the system dependent stuff and are imported into the namespace of the main module.  (e.g. `if sys.platform == 'linux2': import _linux_dependent as submod; ...`).  This has the advantage that it keeps the system dependent code separate.

Comment: This isn't a why, but this *when* may help someone find the answer.  It first appeared in 1990 in Python/compile.c with a commit message of '"Compiling" version' http://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/a6934380c6e7/Python/compile.c#l1112

Comment: Of course, I know how to *workaround* this. But sometimes I just have small modules and this would be simpler.

Comment: `import this` will give you supporting statements why ...

Answer (score 7):

I would guess that this is a decision on the part of the python devs because it forces the **user** of the module to deal with the fact that their system isn't supported (rather than getting the developers of the module to guess what should happen).  Imagine their surprise when they run the code on a windows machine and all of a sudden `module.foo()` doesn't work as they expected.  (Your warning `print` statement could be completely buried in all sorts of other garbage that might get dumped to stdout).

I think that the most idomatic way to handle this is to raise an `ImportError` or `NotImplementedError`.  Then the **user** can decide if they can live without this module and proceed, (by catching the exceptions), or if their program should crash and burn right there.

Comment: I cant think of a single valid reason why one would want to call a return from a module...

Comment: That is quite unusual for Python which usually doesn't force much (much the opposite).

Comment: @Albert -- it doesn't *force* this either.  You're free to enclose your entire module in an `if-elif-else` clause if you feel like it.  For a small module (as you say), this might be an option ...

Comment: @mgilson: Yeah I know but the cases where I was using this just looked ugly. Btw., you can also argue the same about functions -- still it is sometimes useful to return somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Joran Beasley A number of [open-source Python frameworks](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) I co-develop would strongly benefit from the capacity to call `return` from within a module. Your individual inability to envision a valid use case does _not_ imply that no valid use case exists.

Comment: @mgilson Requiring `if-elif-else` constructs merely to circumvent language deficits is both horrible and anti-Pythonic. With any observable luck, an eventual Python 4 will rectify this and other arbitrary syntactic oversights (e.g., the horribleness of confining `lambda` functions to mere expressions).

Comment: @CecilCurry -- I think that confining `lambda` to simple expressions is a good decision.  I've read far too much javascript where the boundaries between one inline-function and the next becomes too difficult to discern :-).  Also, as I stated in the answer, it seems like raising an exception is a better decision than just silently working, but then dying later at an unrelated point because something you expected to be there wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a "why" (I suspect the answer to that is just "`return` belongs in a function and there's no compelling reason to put it in top-level module code"). But it's a tidy workaround that you may not know about. Your code can be refactored as follows without adding much complexity:

```
import sys

def main():
    global foo, bar
    if sys.platform != "linux2":
        print "your platform is not yet supported"
        # define some stubs
        def foo(): pass
        def bar(): pass
        return

main()
```

Comment: I’m new to Python and may use this or just a big else clause. But I don’t use an `else` clause when the `if` returns: the `else` signifies the execution will rejoin (to my mind) and my brains says “whoa! Dude, you just returned! You’re done man!” so that’s ugly too. Of course, not everybody thinks multiple returns from a function are okay, but it works for me in an imperative language because sequence (not composition). Python seems pretty fast and loose, adaptable to the individual (making it fun); more expressiveness, rather than uniformity (good in mission critical work) is a plus.

Comment: You don't need `main` here. Just put the `if` statement at the global level, and define the functions as normal in the `else` branch. (Defining stand-in functions as `pass` is highly dubious in general; you'd typically want either an alternate implementation, or a `raise`.)